# Identifying sentence constituents

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence I was asked to identify the sentence constituents: subject, verb, objects, complement and adverbial/adverb.

I really love dogs, but my wife loves cats.

I=subject, love=verb, dogs=object, really=adverb, my wife=subject, loves=verb and cats=object.
**My question** is: what is the function of the conjunction **but** in terms of the constituents listed above. My teacher says it acts as an adverb , but how?

Comment: "but" is a coordinating conjunction that links the two coordinate clauses.

Comment: Thank you,  I want to know how but functions as a sentence constituent in the sentence.  I understand that on its own it is a coordinating conjunction  that links two simple sentences ,but don't seem to be able to classify it in terms of the constituent functions that I GAVE IN MY INITIAL PREAMBLE.

Comment: What you have to understand is that conjunctions joining clauses are external linking components and do not fit into any of the internal constituent classes you mention. (You needn't have used block capitals. It looks like you are shouting and I'm sure you didn't mean to do so.) One thing is certain: "but" is not an adverb.

Comment: I left my block capital key on by mistake and certainly didn't intend it to look like I was shouting or to be rude, so sorry about that. I appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Comment: It is none of the things that you listed in your introductory statement. I believe that your teacher is misinformed. @Gustavson's comment is both complete and correct, and with brief support could probably be posted as an answer. (If your teacher is a native English speaker who has spoken the language for more than seven decades, and who has taught the language to other native speakers at the secondary and university levels for more than four, I will humbly withdraw the characterization.)

Comment: Another teacher's F.

Comment: There's no doubt at all that "but" is a coordinator in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is wrong. In this sentence “but” a (coordinating) conjunction, not an adverb.

It’s possible that your teacher is confused by the fact that “but” is sometimes an adverb, such as in the sentence

> I have but one chance to get this right.

If we look at the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/but) we see both of these uses listed separately, as well as the note that “but” can be a preposition.

The OED defines “adverb” by saying that

> An adverb is a word that’s used to give information about a verb, adjective, or other adverb.

The only words that “but” could be modifying in your sentence are “really”, “love”, and “loves.” It doesn’t modify “really,” because it in no way qualifies the extent to which you love dogs. But it also doesn’t make sense to say that it modifies either “love” or “loves”. It contrasts those two phrases, but doesn’t give any information about how much you love dogs or how much your wife loves cats.

To try to understand your teacher’s POV, maybe ask them what the role of the word “and” in the sentence “I love ice cream and my sister does too” is. Do they also think that that’s an adverb? This might be a good starting point for a conversation with the teacher about the error.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your time and answers. Like a dog with a bone I kept on researching and found something which seems to say that the conjunction but and other such conjunctions can be considered to be a type of adverb called a conjunct. I will ask my instructor today. This was from a friend's old U of Saskatchewan TESL course. However, I still cant understand how it fits the conventional definition of an adverb in terms of function..